# Difference between ".wsdl"and "?wsdl" in wsdl Url

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, websphere, jax-ws

I have a **jax-ws web service deployed on web sphere server** and when I am trying to access the wsdl in browser with the url

```
"Http://localhost:7001/HelloWorldService/port/helloworld?wsdl"
```

I see that the **url** is getting changed to the below one

```
"Http://localhost:7001/HelloWorldService/port/helloworld/HelloWorldService.wsdl"
```

Can someone explain the **difference between  these both .wsdl and ?wsdl** and **what needs to be done to keep the url same as ?wsdl instead of getting changed to .wsdl?**

Comment: Could you also post the wsdl contents? What are the differences in the wsdl you deploy and the one you can download via `http://localhost:7001/HelloWorldService/port/helloworld/HelloWorldService.wsdl`?

Comment: There is no difference between wsdl file content..both are same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

helloworld?wsdl --> is just a request to the service provider so you can get the wsdl.

HelloWorldService.wsdl" --> This is the actual file that describes the service which has set of endpoints.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. How to keep the url as ?wsdl instead of .wsdl. Do i need to change anything?